# Tomcat Proxy Protocol support

Tags: tomcat, proxy, tomcat7, tomcat8, amazon-elb

Does Tomcat 7 or 8 support the Proxy Protocol used by AWS ELB TCP & SSL listeners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is an open enhancement request for this: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57830